# REMOVE Accordion Panel using Jquery

Tags: jquery, html, accordion, jquery-ui-accordion, removeclass

While searching, I can mostly find how to add a panel using Jquery Accordion and got that to work no problem. **BUT, how do I remove the same panel that I added?**

I have this fiddle:http://jsfiddle.net/cof7ojky/12/ working which adds a panel to the according.

**BUT now I want to REMOVE the same panel I added** similar to this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/m5TMF/163/

Here's my code:

JQuery

```
$(function() {
  $("#accordion").accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    heightStyle: "content"
  });
  $('#sub-project-button').click(function() {
  // Add a new header and panel
  $( "<h3>New Panel</h3>" ).appendTo( "#accordion" );
  $( "<div>jQuery UI sure is awesome!</div>" ).appendTo( "#accordion" );
  // Refresh the accordion
  $( "#accordion" ).accordion( "refresh" );
  });
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="sub-project-button" onclick="changeClassCancel()" type="button" class="btn btn-default">Lorem</button>
<div id="accordion">
  <h3>Section 1</h3>
  <div>
    <p>
    Mauris mauris ante, blandit et, ultrices a, suscipit eget, quam. Integer
    ut neque. Vivamus nisi metus, molestie vel, gravida in, condimentum sit
    amet, nunc. Nam a nibh. Donec suscipit eros. Nam mi. Proin viverra leo ut
    odio. Curabitur malesuada. Vestibulum a velit eu ante scelerisque vulputate.
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

please HELP! thanks in advance! I have a feeling it's simple but can't find after searching for hours

Here is the link I worked with from the Jquery website regarding 'add/remove panels': http://jqueryui.com/upgrade-guide/1.10/#added-ability-to-add-remove-panels, but doesn't how to remove.

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main difference between yours and the example is that he uses a template that is easy to clone and remove. You just add the `<h3>` and then the `<div>` with the content (no wrapper).

To mimic what the example that you provide does, just add a small link to the header than once clicked, it removes the header and the following div (that holds the content of the panel).

This can be achieved with just two small changes in your code:

1) Add the link/button to remove the panel (I have used an `<a>` for simplicity):

```
$("<h3>New Panel<a onclick='removePanel(this)' style='float:right'>X</a></h3>" ).appendTo( "#accordion" );
```

2) Add the function `removePanel(a)` that deletes the elements of the panel that you want to delete (the `<h3>` and the `<div>`):

```
function removePanel(a) {
    // first remove the div, then the header
    $(a).parent().next().remove();
    $(a).parent().remove();
    return false;
}
```

Not the cleanest option, but it works. You can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/cof7ojky/14/

Comment: nice thanks, this helps! one last question, I tried deploying the cloning option that he has in the fiddle and added the external links, but for some reason, I can't get the add functionality to work. Any chance you can give it a try and see if you can launch the cloning option on your computer? Possible to provide the entire code in html format with the <head></head>, similar to what i did in my fiddle? @AlvaradoMontoro

Comment: What you asked in your comment is not a trivial task and requires a big code rewrite: the example you provide creates the accordion using jQuery and Bootstrap; Your code includes Bootstrap, but it is not using it and really creating the jQuery UI accordion. You are basically asking to redo the whole thing!

Comment: Disregard the last comment, was not sure why the cloning option fiddle was not working on my pc, but i simply forgot to add the windows onload or the ready function. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @AlvaradoMontoro Had another question, any idea on how bootstrap tabs can be added using the cloning option method? To be able to add functioning tabs within every new panel that is created. Added new tabs using the cloning option but not able to get them to work after they were added. Let me know, thanks! Also, added question [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28777301/dynamically-add-multiple-bootstrap-tabs-in-one-page-within-an-accordion?noredirect=1#comment45833002_28777301)